# ¿Cómo lograr que un texto salga en una sola línea en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un caso donde quiero mostrar un texto que ocupe todo el ancho de su contenedor y no ocupe mas de una sola línea pero en caso que tenga caracteres separadores de línea no muestre las líneas consecutivas.

Intenté con el siguiente código en CSS puro:

```css
.line-container {
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
}
.single-line {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-container">
  <div class="single-line">Lorem
    ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor
    amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum 
    dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</div>
</div>
```

Esto funciona bien pero solo si no hay caracteres de retorno de línea pues la propiedad [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) cuando se pone en `nowrap` elimina los saltos de línea. Los otros posibles valores `normal`, `pre`, `pre-wrap` y `pre-line` no fueron de mucha ayuda ya que el texto no salía entonces en 1 sola línea.

Leí también que hay varias formas de interpretar la presencia de una nueva línea con los caracteres \r y \n ([retorno de línea y nueva línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) en los siguientes links:

[What is the difference between \r and \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

[https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_Línea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea)

Imagino que si estoy leyendo un texto de una base de datos o un fichero y recibiendolo desde un servidor esto me puede traer muchos inconvenientes si fue escrito en diferentes sistemas operativos.

¿Existe alguna solución en CSS que no conozca o debo usar algún snippet de javascript para crear un componente como el que les estoy mostrando?

Comment: No comprendo, en el texto del ejemplo hay retornos de línea y funciona bien. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en el que se vea el fallo?

Comment: En el ejemplo debería haber mostrado solamente `Lorem` y ocultar el resto del texto ya que lo demás pertenece a otra línea; sin embargo lo que se muestra es `Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem i...` ya que los retornos de línea son eliminados.

Comment: estaba mirando un poco el codigo que dejo, y parece que lo que hace es mostrar los caracteres que pueda hasta que llege en este caso a width: 230px; si cambias a width: 290px; puede ver que muestra mas igual ayuda. Me explico creo que no esta teniendo encuenta si ahi saltos o no simplemente escribe hasta que pueda. Saludos

Comment: Para saber un poco más de este detalle como obtienes el texto que vacias dentro del div, desde la base de datos.

Comment: @Elenasys Estoy usando angular y [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) y estoy mockeando los datos. Esoy usando un `ng-bind` para llenar el div pero imagino que cuando obtenga mis datos de la bd el problema persista. Al darme cuenta de lo que estaba ocurriendo pensé que debía usar una directiva pero el problema es algo trivial así que intenté con CSS y no he logrado que funcione.

Comment: @AngelAngel La propiedad `text-overflow` trunca el texto que se desborda siempre y cuando este no se muestre, por eso uso `overflow: hidden`. Si es mayor que esas medidas no se mostrará y `text-overflow` se encargará de cortarlo.

Comment: acabo de volver a leer su pregunta, e igual puede hacer una pruebas desde la db o simularlo y aplicar esta respuesta -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string/10805198#10805198 basado en esta parte de su pregunta -> Imagino que si estoy leyendo......diferentes sistemas operativos, igual lo soluciona. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es exactamente lo contrario. Yo necesito preservar los saltos de línea, la respuesta de SO que me muestras también se puede lograr con CSS con el estilo `white-space: nowrap;` como esta en mi pregunta. En caso que el texto de la primera línea sea muy largo se puede especificar continuidad con ... con el estilo `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, en caso que haya un retorno de línea debe mostrar sólo el texto hasta el salto pero sólo _si este es más pequeño que su contenedor_

Comment: ahh siento no haber entendido que queria los saltos de linea. Saludos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Al fin logré lo que quería. No tuve que usar javascript, solo CSS.

De esta forma pude lograr una solución portable para cualquier entorno e increiblemente segun el spec puede funcionar hasta en Internet Explorer 6.

Resulta que la propiedad [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) cuando se pone en `pre` si preserva los saltos de línea, incluso tiene en cuenta cuando se encuentra con un elemento `<br/>` pero crea este efecto curioso.

```js
$(function() {
  var textoLargo = 'Lorem ipsum dolor amet ipsum dolor amet ipsum dolor amet ipsum dolor amet\r\n' +
    'ipsum dolor\r\n' +
    'amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum\n' +
    'dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\r' +
    'Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\n';
  $('#empty').html(textoLargo);
});
```

```css
.line-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
.single-line {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Probando distintos separadores</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div id="empty" class="single-line">
  </div>
</div>
<h3 style="margin-top: 100px">Usando elementos br como separadores</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    <br/>Lorem ipsum
    <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que hace es es crear pequeños fragmentos de texto recortados. La propiedad [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) cuando se pone en `ellipsis` recorta el texto que sobrepasa el tamaño de su contenedor, por eso es necesario usar `overflow: hidden;` en conjunto con la propiedad `white-space` para que se muestre la elípsis `...` en caso que el texto sea más grande.

Llegando ahí solo tuve que aplicarle otro `overflow: hidden;` al contenedor y listo!

```js
$(function() {
  var textoLargo = 'Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\r\n' +
    'ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor\r\n' +
    'amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum\n' +
    'dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\r' +
    'Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\n';
  var primeraLineaCorta = 'Lorem ipsum dolor \r\n' +
    'ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor\r\n' +
    'amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum\n' +
    'dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\r' +
    'Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet\n';
  $('#long').html(textoLargo);
  $('#short').html(primeraLineaCorta);
});
```

```css
.line-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.single-line {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h3>Probando distintos separadores</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div id="long" class="single-line">
  </div>
</div>
<h3 style="margin-top: 30px">Si el texto es mas pequeño</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div id="short" class="single-line">
  </div>
</div>
<h3 style="margin-top: 30px">Si se usa br como separador</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div id="short" class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    <br/>Lorem ipsum
    <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 style="margin-top: 30px">Si se usa br y el texto es pequeño</h3>
<div class="line-container">
  <div id="short" class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sólo es necesario usar este pequeño snippet de css para lograrlo

```
.line-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.single-line {
    width: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

**Nota:** Según la documentación de la propiedad `white-space` esta solución no funciona cuando sólo se usa `\r` como separador. Según el [articulo de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) eso solo aplica a las Macs más antiguas lo cual creo que es bastante aceptable. Si este es el caso habría que reemplazar los caracteres de retorno `\r` por `\n` usando javascript para lograr este efecto.

Answer (score 1):

El div padre que contiene al div que muestra el texto, tiene una medida fija, eso no permite se muestre correctamente el texto, elimina la clase `.line-container`

```
<style>
.single-line {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<div class="line-container">
<div class="single-line" >Lorem
    ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor
    amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum 
    dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</div>
</div>
```

ve el ejemplo online **[aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/am8Lr2ay/)**

Te comento también que si tu texto llegar a tener saltos de linea o retornos de linea, por medio de Javascript podrías filtrar esos caracteres no imprimibles, por ejemplo:

```
var s = "Lorem \n  ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor \n amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum \n dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem\n ipsum dolor amet";
```

Usando esta regex y el método replace() puedes eliminar los saltos de línea y retornos:

```
s = s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

Comment: Creo que andas por buen camino. Creo que debería usar javascript para manejar los retornos y quizás como sugirió @Fakux usar <br/> pero el container no se puede eliminar ya que eso es lo que quiero lograr. Restringir el tamaño del contenedor para poder ver como se comporta con diferentes tamaños y textos. Lo que estoy intentando es algo como el sistema de notificaciones de SOes excepto que ahi puede haber cualquier tipo de contenido por lo que la solución debe ser genérica. Lo que sé hasta ahora es que el contenedor tendrá tamaño fijo y se debe indicar continuación de texto con tres puntos

Answer (score 1):

Importante que no tenga párrafos el texto. Sino te va a hacer el salto de linea en cada comienzo de párrafo.
Aparte del ellipsis y demás, hay que definirle el width al texto para que se corte.

```css
.line-container {
  width: 230px;
  height: 20px;
}

.single-line {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-container">
  <p class="single-line">
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias agregar un `"<br/>"` donde queres que haga el salto de linea

El motivo es que html no interpreto un "enter" como un salto de linea =)

Comment: Estoy usando [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) para generar mis datos y esa librería **si** genera el texto con saltos de línea. Tu respuesta asume que yo estoy escribiendo el html manualmente y si por ejemplo los datos vienen de una base de datos esa solución como está ya no es posible.

Comment: 1) Si estas usando faker.js ,especificalo en tu pregunta.
2) En una base de datos podes guardar un '<br\>' en un campo de tipo varchar.
3) No comprendo que es lo que queres hacer pero en todo caso deberias modificar el ancho de tu width para que solo alcanze para una paralabra.

Comment: El hecho que esté usando faker.js no tiene relevancia ya que eventualmante este será eliminado de la aplicación y el problema aún persistirá. La otra solución tampoco es buena ya que si estas llenando un formulario con un `textarea` por ejemplo lo que te enviará es un retorno de línea y modificar todo un api para manejar esta posibilidad me parece una solución demasiado extrema. Debe haber una solución mucho más sencilla.